# A 5-bit S-Box whose differential branch number is equal to 4 and the linear branch number is not less than 3

Tags: block-cipher, s-boxes, permutation

The last paragraph of Section 1 (Introduction) of the paper [“On the Relationship between Resilient Boolean Functions and Linear Branch Number of S-boxes”](https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/1427) [S. Sarkar, K. Mandal, D. Saha] contains the following text:

> For an $n \times n$ S-box $S$, its linear branch number, denoted by $\mathcal{LBN}(S)$, satisfies $\mathcal{LBN}(S) \leq n - 1,$ and its differential branch number, denoted by $\mathcal{DBN}(S)$, satisfies $\mathcal{DBN}(S) \leq \lceil \frac{2n}{3} \rceil.$ It is also interesting to note that ASCON and SYCON use $5 \times 5$ S-boxes that have differential branch number $3$ and linear branch number $3.$

Section VI.B of the paper [“Finding Desirable Substitution Box with SASQUATCH”](https://eprint.iacr.org/2023/742) [M. Wadhwa, A. Baksi, K. Hu, A. Chattopadhyay, T. Isobe, D. Saha] contains an example of the $5$-bit S-Box with the differential branch number equal to $4,$ but its linear branch number is $2.$

Does there exist a $5$-bit S-Box $S$ such that the differential branch number of $S$ is equal to $4$ and the linear branch number of $S$ is not less than $3?$ If no, why? If yes, is there any known example of such an S-Box (assuming that $S$ is cryptographically useful — for example, its algebraic degree is not less than $2,$ nonlinearity greater than $0$ etc.)?

Comment: can you give more context? what is known? reference?